# Change background of a card when radio selected

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, bootstrap-5

My question is very simple : how to add a background color to my card element when the button radio is selected ?

```html
<div class="col-6 col-md-3 mt-4 text-center my-auto">
            <label for="'.$abreviation.'">
                <div class="card card-block d-flex">
                    <div class="card-body align-items-center d-flex justify-content-center">
                        <input type="radio" id="'.$abreviation.'" name="tri" value="'.$abreviation.'" class="check-on" /> '.$tri.'
                    </div>
                </div>
            </label>
        </div>
```

Is there any way to achieve this with just css or I have to use javascript or jquery ?
I tried to do this but all of the cards are in a red backgroundColor instead of just the card where the radio is selected.

```js
    $(document).ready(function(){

        $(".check-on").click(function(){

          $('.check-on').parent().parent().addClass('backgroundCard') 

        });

    });
```

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Add ```$(this).closest('.card').addClass('backgroundCard') ``` instead.

Comment: Won't you need to detect if checked or not and add/remove background based on this?

Comment: yes I would like to add and remove

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You don't need to bind a label to an input with the `for` attribute when the `input` tag is inside a `label` tag.
2. The card can be styled without any JS. To do this, you can place a card next to the input field, hide the input using the `d-none` class, and use the [adjacent element combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_combinator).

Try to click the cards. They work as radio buttons now.

```css
input[type="radio"]:checked + .card {
  background: #f1f1f1;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-6 col-md-3 mt-4 text-center my-auto">
    <label>
        <input type="radio" name="tri" value="'.$abreviation.'" class="d-none" />
        <div class="card card-block d-flex">
            <div class="card-body align-items-center d-flex justify-content-center">
                '.$tri.'
            </div>
        </div>
    </label>
</div>

<div class="col-6 col-md-3 mt-4 text-center my-auto">
    <label>
        <input type="radio" name="tri" value="'.$abreviation2.'" class="d-none" /> 
        <div class="card card-block d-flex">
            <div class="card-body align-items-center d-flex justify-content-center">
                '.$tri.'
            </div>
        </div>
    </label>
</div>

<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

Comment: Best approach for this type, and no js required.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".check-on").click(function(){
          $(this).parent().parent().addClass('backgroundCard')
    });
});
```

once you have focused on the clicked element, keep focus on that only using `this` selector. You where again selecting all by class

Comment: Oh I tried with this but I forgot the $... So how can I do to get back and removeClass when clicking in other radio ?

Answer (score 0):

You can add and remove class with `on change` event.

In case you have multiple radio groups, you can get the `name` of those radio and based on this you can remove the class of the correct cards:

```
$(this).attr('name');
```

```js
$('.check-on').on('change', function() {
  let radioName = $(this).attr('name');
  $(`.check-on[name=${radioName}]`).closest('.card.backgroundCard').removeClass('backgroundCard');
  $(this).closest('.card').addClass('backgroundCard');
});
```

```css
.card.backgroundCard {
  background: #f1f1f1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="col-6 col-md-3 mt-4 text-center my-auto">
    <label for="'.$abreviation.'">
        <div class="card card-block d-flex">
            <div class="card-body align-items-center d-flex justify-content-center">
                <input type="radio" id="'.$abreviation.'" name="tri" value="'.$abreviation.'" class="check-on" /> '.$tri.'
            </div>
        </div>
    </label>
</div>

<div class="col-6 col-md-3 mt-4 text-center my-auto">
    <label for="'.$abreviation2.'">
        <div class="card card-block d-flex">
            <div class="card-body align-items-center d-flex justify-content-center">
                <input type="radio" id="'.$abreviation2.'" name="tri" value="'.$abreviation2.'" class="check-on" /> '.$tri.'
            </div>
        </div>
    </label>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

No need for Javascript or Jquery to do this. Just simple CSS is enough.

```css
/* This css is for normalizing styles. You can skip this. */
*, *:before, *:after {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.new {
  padding: 50px;
}

.form-group {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.form-group input {
  padding: 0;
  height: initial;
  width: initial;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  display: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.form-group label {
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px;
}

.form-group label:before {
  content: '';
    position: absolute;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    background-color: transparent;
    border: 2px solid #0079bf;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}

.form-group input:checked + label:after {
  content: '';
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #0079bf;
    z-index: -1;
  
}
```

```html
<div class="new">
  <form>
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="radio" id="$tri-1" name="radio">
      <label for="$tri-1">$tri-1</label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="radio" id="$tri-2" name="radio">
      <label for="$tri-2">$tri-2</label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="radio" id="$tri-3" name="radio">
      <label for="$tri-3">$tri-3</label>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```